# Where should I read my username and password for my WCF Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

I have a WPF application that has just one button.  When the button is clicked, all it does is open the service.  Here is the code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference1.TestServiceClient c = new ServiceReference1.TestServiceClient();

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\Test\Test.xml");

        c.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = doc.Root.Element("Credentials").Attribute("username").Value;
        c.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = doc.Root.Element("Credentials").Attribute("password").Value;

        try
        {
            c.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

As you can see from above, I am reading the username and password from a Credentials node in an xml file to validate the client.  Is it proper to have it located here, because originally, I had it defined in my Validate method:

```
 public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {

       // XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\Test\Test.xml");

       // userName = doc.Root.Element("Credentials").Attribute("username").Value;
      //  password = doc.Root.Element("Credentials").Attribute("password").Value;


        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("userName");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("password");

        // check if the user is not test
        if (userName != "test" || password != "test")
            throw new FaultException("Username and Password Failed");
    }
```

But the problem with the above is that whatever I pass into c.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName and c.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password gets overriden when it reaches the Validate method.  For example, in my button click, if I just have:

`c.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test1";`
`c.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "test1";`

The above should fail, but when it goes into the Validate method where I read the xml file that has the username and password attribute as test and test, it will pass.

As a side note, I noticed that my Validate method gets called, but I can't seem to step into.  The debugger symbols don't get loaded.

Comment: Why are you doing the security yourself, instead of relying on WCF's built in security capabilities?

Comment: Can you clarify?  I am using the overriding the Validate method of UserNamePasswordValidator.  Isn't this how to do it?  All I am doing is reading in the user and password from an xml file.

Comment: No - the way to do it would be to use either Windows credentials (in a LAN/corporate environment), or to use e.g. the ASP.NET Membership system. Let WCF do all the checking and everything - you just set up the place it has to go look for valid users and passwords.

Comment: @marc_s,  Here is my scenario.  I am not using ASP.NET Membership or a Custom Membership provider.  I have to validate the username and password in the database and I get the users name and password by reading an xml file.  How do I set the username and password that will be passed in the Validate method.  Don't I have to set the ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName and ClientCredentials.UserName.Password outside of the Validate method?

Comment: Why can't you put a custom membership provider in place?? That would be **by far** the easiest way to get your own database into the WCF security game.....

Comment: @marc_s, I agree, but I am working with a legacy db that is a real mess and all the users are stored in a table called Users with a column UserName and Password, so this is what I have to do for now,  I just want to make sure that If this is the way the users are stored, then am I doing it right?

Comment: What do you mean by overriden? Aren't the username and password parameters at the Validate method equal to the credentials sent by the client?

Comment: @Predo, I got this to work as well. I think I thought it wasn't because I could never step into the Validate method, so it was throwing me off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are overwriting the parameter with your read

```
 public override void Validate(string suppliedUserName, string suppliedPassword){
     // ...
     string validUserName = doc.Root.Element("Credentials").Attribute("username").Value;
     string validPassword = doc.Root.Element("Credentials").Attribute("password").Value;
```